# Is dateModified in the webiste related with the index and updating it?

Tags: html, sitemap, datemodified

When I open an article web page on a website. And I click on the right click of the mouse. then chose "View Page Source"

Then we search about dateModified. Here we can find the last update on the article.

Is dateModified related with the index and updating the index ?

Can I depend on dateModified to see the last update on the content of the article webapge ?

And with sitemap way. Is sitemap relateed with index and updating it ?

Can I depend on sitemap to see the last update on the content of the article webapge ?

And also what is the best way to know when was the last update on the content of the webpage ?

Comment: _"Then we search about dateModified. Here we can find the last update on the article."_ - Please describe **exactly** what "dateModified" value you are looking at. It sounds like you're referring to a datetime in the HTML source code - in which case you are mistaken: it's entirely up to the website what is puts in the HTML it gives you. If you're referring to the `Last-Modified` HTTP header, then you need to understand it is still under the full-control of the website and could be an entirely fake value.

Comment: @Dai dateModified exist in the source code page. and next to dateModified there is the date and time

Comment: I don't think you understood what I wrote...

Comment: @Dai In the HTTP header. under request headers. there is something called "If-Modified-Since". and next to it , there is time and date. what about this ? is it it last update on the content of the webpage ?

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the index"?

Comment: Do you understand how HTTP works? And server-side rendering of dynamic HTML?

Comment: @Dai I don't really know this. but I want to know if it realted with index.

Comment: @Dai I am still beginner. I don't know. I just want to know how to know the last update on the content of the webpage.

Comment: There is no such thing as "index" in the web. Are you thinking of `index.html`? If so, that's an _implementation concern_: websites do not have to use `index.html` and few websites today use static files.

Comment: _"I just want to know how to know the last update on the content of the webpage."_ - The simple answer is **you can't**. The web is not just a bunch of static HTML files on-disk - and the `Last-Modified` header is not authoritative.

Comment: @dai I don't mean index.html. just anything related by index. So dateModified doesn't realteed with anything related with index ?

Comment: _" just anything related by index"_ - I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: @Dai I will repeat it. Is dateModified doesn't related with index ?

Comment: @dai Actually I read an article about how to know the last update on the webpage. and they use dateModified

Comment: There is no such thing as an "index" in a website - you read a misleading or incorrect article. The web is **not** made up of static HTML files all on-disk: the vast majority og web-pages are dynamically rendered (just like this one on StackOverflow) so it cannot have a meaningful "last modified" timestamp.

Comment: @dai Actually someone how told me that dateModified related with index.
thank you for help.

Comment: @dai "I just want to know how to know the last update on the content of the webpage." this was my question. but threre is a mistake in it. so i will repeat it. Is there way to know when was the latest update on the content of the webpage ?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: @dai okay thank you. but I have another question. what is the value of dateModified ? When i saw it. there was a value next to it. and it was "2023-09-01T05:14:09-07:00" so what is this value ?

Comment: …what do you think it is? Have you never seen an RFC 3339 time stamp before?

Comment: @dai I am sorry. I don't know this. okay dateModified doesn't related with the content of the webpage. thank you very much. this helped me.